# Google Earth Plug-in ver 7.0.3.8542 Prompts for username/password credentials

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I'm running into an issue with Google Earth plug-in ver 7.0.3.8542.  The previous version I was on did not have this issue 6.0.2.2074.

I have a SharePoint 2010 WebPart that loads these KML files into the Google Earth Plug-in.  These KML files live in a SharePoint Document Library.  When I select the KML file to load into the plug-in i'm prompted to authenticate with username/password.  I get the following prompt:

The server at  would like you to authenticate for . Please enter your username and password.

In the past with ver. 6.0.2.2074 I was never prompted. I can select the KML file and it would load fine within the plugin.

Has anyone else experienced this?  It looks like the Plug-in is having to re-authenticate to load the KMLs, and its not accepting the passing of KCD or Integrated Windows Auth.

Any help on this would be of great help.

Thank you

v/r
JShidell

Comment: quickly check if you can access the kml via url.

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth Pro 7.1.5 and earlier requires a license key. If you do not have a key, use your email address and the key GEPFREE to sign in.